# Animations are acting like in queue

Tags: css

I have this piece of code

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
}

[theme="dark"]
{
  --bgcolor: #292929;
  --pagecolor: #141414;
  --navcolor: #212121;
  --txtcolor: white;
}

[theme="light"]
{
  --bgcolor: white;
  --pagecolor: yellow;
  --navcolor: #212121;
  --txtcolor: black;
}

html
{
  background-color: var(--pagecolor);
}

body
{
  background-color: var(--bgcolor);
  color: var(--txtcolor);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs" theme="dark">
<body>
    <nav>
        <h3 onclick="document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', document.documentElement.getAttribute('theme') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')">Change color</h3>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have no idea, why the text doesn't transition simultaneously. I've searched a lot, but no one seems to have the same problem. Can somebody demystify this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the transition to all elements.
Write the **background-color** transition inside **html** selector, and write the **color** inside **body**:

```
html {
       background-color: var(--pagecolor);
       transition: background-color 1s;
}

body {
       background-color: var(--bgcolor);
       color: var(--txtcolor);
       transition: color 1s;
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve anything and adds another bug on top.

Comment: Are you certain? works fine:

 https://codepen.io/amirhshahbazi/pen/WNjKXYz

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I left transition property in *. But I'm wondering why is this happening. Doesn't seem like the transition has some kind of queue for its animations.